# SVN+Eclipse: I have to checkout my own code after commit

Tags: windows, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I often come upon a very strange behaviour when **committing code** to **svn** via **eclipse**.

For example I **commit** my **code successfully** at the end of my work day and then I turn my pc off.

The next day I check **incoming changes** and then I have to **checkout my own code**, I committed the day before.

This started happening after I got a new ThinkPad.

I have multiple Eclipse Workspaces which (I think) all seem to have this behaviour.

I think that my revision may stay after the commit or it somehow switches back to that old revision, but I can't really tell since this doesn't always happen.

Some extra info:

I'm working on this project simultaneously with VS Code for JavaScript and Eclipse for Java.

Eclipse:

- Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers
- Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)
- Build id: 20201210-1552
- Subclipse 4.33
- SVN-Interface: SVNKit (Pure Java) SVNKit v1.10.1.10793

PC-Info:

- Processor:    Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz   2.30 GHz
- Installed RAM 16,0 GB (15,8 GB verwendbar)
- Systemtype:   64-Bit, x64-based CPU

Edition Windows 11 Pro

- Version   21H2
- Systembuild   22000.493

Comment: I would rather assume that it is something outside of Eclipse and not caused by Subclipse. Is this your personal ThinkPad and what operating system are you using? For example, if your new computer is property of and administered by the company you work for, it may well be that your account profile is synchronized which might causing this.

Comment: I added some info about my pc. It is a company laptop but I have full access to it/installed everything my self after receiving the pc.
I am using the "C:\Users\username\eclipse_workspace>" for my eclipse workspaces.
Thank you for your comment, I'll investigate this further.